# How to split an array of cells in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing, nokogiri

Code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
showings = []
doc.css('.ok-product').each do |showing|
  showing_id = showing['data-cart-id'].to_i 
  price = showing.at_css('.ok-product__price-main').text.gsub(/[\u0440\u0443\u0431.]/, '').strip
  showings.push(
    id: showing_id,
    price: price
  )
end

CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << showings
end
```

I get the data in csv in cell A1:

```
{:id=>26999, :price=>"395,00"},"{:id=>26963, :price=>""254,00""}"...
```

Need break the data into cells and remove unnecessary symbols.

Comment: What do you call cells?

Comment: Now all in A1. But I need: A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3 ...

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimal input data necessary to demonstrate the problem. What is `html`? Without that your question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  showings.each do |id_price|
    csv << [id_price[:id], id_price[:price]]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you.
And if in cells A1 and B1?

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to give an example (in csv) of what the data should look like, @Mamom

Comment: I made it a script in csv

Comment: Its useful to add a header line for parsing later on, allowing you to treat the columns as hash values (or clarity when reading / testing). (; = newline)

e.g.
`CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv| ;
  csv << "showing_id, price" ;
  showings.each do |showing| ;
    csv << [showing[:id], showing[:price]] ;
  end ;
end ;`